# Why do I see only 3.24 GB memory on my 64-bit system?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory

I have 4GB RAM installed, and I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Why does Windows see only 3.24GB ? What can I do to make it see the full 4GB ?

Comment: It sounds like your chipset/memory controller isn't mapping physical RAM addresses into areas > 4 GB when they conflict with devices.  If you're lucky there's settings in the BIOS that can fix it, if you're not then the chipset only supports 4 GB of RAM, whether it's used by devices or RAM and you're stuck.

Answer (score 5):

The rest is probably used by your integrated graphics chip.

Comment: thank's for the help, but how i can be Sure ?

Comment: @Gold - install a graphics card - it doesn't have to be the best!

Comment: When you boot your computer, go into the BIOS settings (should be a key like DEL or F12... try button-mashing). There it should explain how much RAM is being used by your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

See what's being used

Run 
**devmgmt.msc**

click on view then **Resources by type**, then expand memory.  See what range your video card is using.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check what are the available resources use:

[CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)
 And are you sure your OS is 64 bit cos, I get ~3.24 GB but the reason is that I am using 32 bit OS
Best way to see your resources utilisation use NOD32's System Inspector